# How to optimize LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, arima

Good day everyone,

I am using LSTM to predict a time series data(to be specific stock data). But whenever I am predicting out into the future the result is always very, very poor. My question is, what are they key parameters that I need to tweak in other to improve my result. And apart from tweaking those parameters is there any special technic that a rookie like me who only depends on tutorial videos on YouTube don't know.

secondly, can there be any time series data that an LSTM model cannot predict to a reasonable degree of accuracy. I asked because in case of ARIMA, I heard in a tutorial video that once the data is a white noise, it cannot be use for prediction as there is no regular pattern in the data. So, is this situation also true for LSTM model.

thirdly, based on experience which one performs better, LSTM or GRU.

thanks

I try to predict out into the future using LSTM model but my result is off point. I was expecting some semblance of accuracy in the result but there was none.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.